# Recursive select does not return date list

Tags: mysql, sql, date, recursion

I've trying to made a SELECT returns a date list from a table, starting from a date and bringing previous dates to it, that contains a start date and a number to limit the requests.

```
SELECT sysdate - rownum 
FROM table_01 
WHERE rownum < 50;

SELECT start_date - rownum 
FROM table_01 
WHERE date_ = 'DATA_FINAL'AND rownum < date_limit;
```

The first select is a functional sample of what I'm trying to do with the second select, using the table columns.

[Table I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2xJW.png)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results *as text tables* would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want a "tally" table and `join` to generate multiple rows for each row in the original data:

```
with numbers as (
      select rownum as n
      from table_01
      where rownum < 50
     )
select t1.start_date - n 
from table_01 t1 join
     numbers n
     on n.n < t1.date_limit
where t1.date_ = 'DATA_FINAL';
```

Comment: you're a mind reader, incredible.

Comment: It worked very well, thank you!! But how I do to show the start_date (20200930) before subtraction?

Comment: You want your numbers to start at 0 instead of 1.  Just subtract 1 in the CTE.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked very well and now is showing the start_date too!